# \hline issue with LaTex when importing table from different .tex file into a tabular environment

Tags: import, latex, tabular, pdflatex

I'm having an issue where at certain points using the \hline function creates an error  and instead displays the word "height" where there should be a line. This is happening only when I use an /hline immediately after using a \input{".../filename.tex"} command in a tabular environment. Interestingly, though, adding an \hline to the last row of the file I am importing produces an \hline properly. Does anyone have an idea why this may be the case and what I can do to fix it so that I can add the \hline to the main file and not the files I'm importing. Note that I use TexMaker and MiKTeX

Here are some examples of my code that doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{12pt, english}{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document} 

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption} \label{tab:label} \centering
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline
   \import{".../filename.tex"}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{minipage}{0.95}
Notes are here
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

where filename.tex looks like this (with nothing else):

```
& Mean & SD & N \\
\midrule
Var 1 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
Var 2 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
Var 3 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
Var 4 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
Var 5 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
```

When I move the last \hline to the end of filname.tex, however, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same trick as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50700/36296

Other problems:

- the syntax `\documentclass{12pt, english}{article}` is wrong
- the `booktabs` package is missing
- missing unit in `\begin{minipage}{0.95}`
- you really, really, really shouldn't use the `tabu` package, it is more or less completely broken
- don't load the same package multiple times

```
\documentclass[12pt, english]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
%\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.tex}
& Mean & SD & N \\
\midrule
Var 1 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
Var 2 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
Var 3 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
Var 4 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
Var 5 & 1 & 0 & 1000 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\primitiveinput[1]
{\@@input #1 }
\makeatother


\begin{document} 

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption} \label{tab:label} \centering
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline
   \primitiveinput{test}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{minipage}{0.95cm}
Notes are here
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```